# send id from view to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that receives a Model and displays info of that model.
I have a submit button and when it is clicked i want it to send the id to the method to process it and delete a row that has such id.

How can I do this? I want to use a `button` not an html link like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.Id }) |
```

Thanks!

I tried input type hidden but hasn't worked =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a form to do this... I don't use razor, but an equivalent .aspx way to do this would be:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "myaction", new { Id = 1 }))
  { %>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
<%} %>
```

This will post to ~/Home/myaction/1

Just call Html.BeginForm with the appropriate razor syntax.

Comment: A million thanks! i didn't think the same as html link could be done with the begin form!!

Comment: @bb2: this is also good practice, to use a form submission which does an HTTP POST, rather than a link which does a GET. It's bad practice to have a GET request which actually changes something on the server, which a delete link surely does.

Comment: As @Carson63000 mentioned, then its bad practice to use GET for Create/Delete operation due to the security. An example could be that someone sends you an email with: `<img src="yoursite.com/delete/50" />` and as soon as you load the picture from the email, the GET will be fired.